# LG G2 proximity sensor

Tags: lg-g2, proximity-sensor, hard-reset

I found a big issue in my LG G2 proximity sensor. During a phone call the screen doesn't turn off and the automatic screen lightness doesn't work. This problems happened many times a day. I also tried to do an hard reset but I got the same issue just after the reset reboot (without any app). Sometimes also the gravity sensor holds (screen doesn't turn), but this not so often as proximity sensor problem.
I installed a sensor test app and this app doesn't work too (sometimes got data sometimes not).

What can it be?

Firstly I thought about an software problem, after the hard reset I thought an hardware problem, but it is very strange all this trouble on a 2month old phone. These problems started 2 weeks ago.

Is there in android a system log or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue with G2 after display replacement. Unfortunately this could be solved only by replacing the proximity sensor itself (via warranty repair). From the information I found out on the web

The most disturbing issue was that I could not unlock the phone in dark light environment (the screen immediately turned off when I tried to go past the lockscreen).

Comment: I tried to replace the sensor, but the problem still happends

Answer (score 0):

If you're still experiencing the issue, I am making the assumption that you have an international LG G2 (D802) so you should try and diagnose the issue as you said by looking at some sort of log or even a test.
Open the dialer and type this string into it and a service menu should appear.

```
3845#*802#
```

After this, click on "HW Device Test" and then "ALC Proximity Text".
Let us know how you get on from there.

Comment: From this test I get "no data" and no way to change it...

Answer (score 0):

I had proximity detector issue when I replaced my LG G2 VS980 LCD and screen.  I found that disconnecting it and removing it was a great solution for me.  If I need to hold phone to my ear I simply push the power button to turn off screen.  The other thing I noticed is that phone does not know its orientation but that will not matter for most people because, although phone does not know "what way it is pointed" it knows "where it is" so GPS works fine.  Using apps to identify things in the sky like planes and stars will likely not work though.

Comment: Voiding warranty by manipulating the hardware is not the best solution – especially when it removes other device features. I doubt this is the OP's intention.

Answer (score 0):

my screen also bugs on my G2 D802 , on random unlocks and on all callls i cant open screen to end calls .

mike i will reply , the proximity test on what you said is NEAR with yellow letters and light is 0.00

***my temporary solution is this :
plug ANYTHING to your phone ! i usually go aorund with headphones so i am ok , but when not , i have a small jack ( 2 inputs 1 output ) and just plug it to open the screen :)